# Space after \textquotedblright

Tags: spacing, punctuation

I am trying to put a text in "" using `\textquotedblleft` and  `\textquotedblright`. It works perfectly fine except it does not put ANY space after `\textquotedblright`. In other words, `BEFORE \textquotedblleft TEXT \textquotedblright AFTER` comes out as BEFORE "TEXT"AFTER. Is there any way to fix it? One obvious way is using `BEFORE \textquotedblleft TEXT \textquotedblright \ AFTER`. I was wondering if there is any better way to fix this. Thanks

Comment: `\textquotedblright` like any other TeX command gobbles following spaces unless you place `{}` or `\ ` after it. I'd rather use [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) for quotes, anyway.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150945/9075 for a long discussion for quotes. Maybe it helps to solve the underlying issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\textquotedblleft` and `\textquotedblright` (as well as most other commands without arguments, which do not use the [xspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace) package) gobble their following space (as if the name was `\textquotedblleft␣`). To get a space character there, you need to use `\textquotedblleft{}` and `\textquotedblright{}`. You could also use explicit space (e.g. `\␣` (slash space) or `\hspace{1em}`), but you want the space to be stretchable, dont't you? Alternatively, as suggested by [cgnieder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/cgnieder), the [csquotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package can be used for quotes.

Comment: The usual shortcuts as well as the `babel` shortcuts would also be a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the `xspace` package:

   ```
   \usepackage{xspace}
   ```

   and define a new command as (for example)

   ```
   \newcommand{\tqdr}{\textquotedblright\xspace}
   ```
2. (easier): Use shorthands as ``` `` ``` and `''`

Answer (score 2):

If you:

- aren't comfortable with the shorthands (suggested by Luis Parrado)
- don't want to have to remember to use `{}` or `\␣` (as noted by Stephen and cgnieder)
- don't want to bother with the huge `csquotes` package
- recognise that `xspace` can cause more problems than it solves,...

then why not just define your own macro that takes an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\textquotedouble}[1]{\textquotedblleft #1\textquotedblright}
\begin{document}
    BEFORE \textquotedouble{TEXT} AFTER.
\end{document}
```

(And perhaps use a shorter name than this!)

Note: I personally prefer the shorthands myself!