# Automatic german quotation marks

Tags: punctuation, german

I would like to compile a file according to German standards, in which quotation marks are to be put like this:
`\glqq text \grqq`

In my LaTeX document I use quotation marks in the standard way: `''text''`

Is there a possibility to change in the preamble that `''` will be compiled - depending on its location to `\glqq` or `\grqq`? Or an even simpler solution?

EDIT: Sorry for the incomplete desciption. I was referring to the german standards which are: „“

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`csqoutes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package

Comment: Thats a great package, thanks for the suggestion! Using this one I will have to replace all ''...'' that I have with environments like \enquote etc. I was wondering if there was a simpler way without changing the ''?

Comment: @HenriMenke you means `csquotes`.

Comment: `''text''` is not the standard way, `\`\`text''` is. But for German I recommend using `babel`'s shorthands ``"`text"'``

Comment: Yes, very good point @cgnieder.

Comment: I am familliar with the German quotation marks, but aren't guillemets preferred for German in a typesetting scenario?

Comment: Chevrons are sometimes, but not commonly, used. Guillemets are used in French.

Comment: @TimSeguine „Text“ is the primary, more used standard. »Text« is the secondary standard, used for typographically more advanced stuff. Cf. also [International variation in quotation marks – Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_variation_in_quotation_marks).

Comment: @Speravir I live in Germany and at least 90% of the (many) books on my bookshelf use guillemets for quotes. Just saying.

Comment: @TimSeguine: What I said ;-) “typographically advanced” … or let’s call it “typographically ambitious”. (Where is Wernau? Ah, I see “Stuttgart area”.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably this will cause some other troubles, but here it is.

Elaborating a bit on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10676/27635) of Martin Scharrer, this is the result:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\let\oldquote'
\newif\ifquoteopen
\catcode`\'=\active
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{'}{%
   \@ifnextchar'{%
     \ifquoteopen
       \global\quoteopenfalse\grqq\expandafter\@gobble
     \else
       \global\quoteopentrue\glqq\expandafter\@gobble
     \fi
   }{\oldquote}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Using ''quotes''}
A ''quote'' and one with a period that follows: ''quote''. And a single 'quote'.

\noindent
And this is the original one: \glqq quote\grqq.
\end{document}
```

---

If the meaning of `'` in math mode is to be preserved, some other hacks are needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\let\oldquote'
\newif\ifquoteopen
\catcode`\'=\active
\makeatletter
% we have to redefine \pr@m@s to use an active '
\def\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}
\protected\def'{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\active@math@prime
  \else
    \expandafter\active@text@prime
  \fi}
\def\active@text@prime{%
   \@ifnextchar'{%
     \ifquoteopen
       \global\quoteopenfalse\grqq\expandafter\@gobble
     \else
       \global\quoteopentrue\glqq\expandafter\@gobble
     \fi
   }{\oldquote}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Using ''quotes''}
A ''quote'' and one with a period that follows: ''quote''. And a single 'quote'.

\noindent
And this is the original one: \glqq quote\grqq.

\noindent
Some derivatives $f'(x)+g''(x)$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This last solution also transforms single quotes into German ones:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}

\let\oldquote'
\newif\ifquoteopen
\catcode`\'=\active
\makeatletter
% we have to redefine \pr@m@s to use an active '
\def\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}
\protected\def'{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\active@math@prime
  \else
    \expandafter\active@text@prime
  \fi}
\def\active@text@prime{%
   \@ifnextchar'{%
     \ifquoteopen
       \global\quoteopenfalse\grqq\expandafter\@gobble
     \else
       \global\quoteopentrue\glqq\expandafter\@gobble
     \fi
   }{%
     \ifquoteopen
       \global\quoteopenfalse\grq\xspace
     \else
       \global\quoteopentrue\glq
     \fi
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Using ''quotes''}
A ''quote'' and one with a period that follows: ''quote''. A single 'quote' and one with a period that follows: 'quote'.

\noindent
And these are the original ones: \glqq quote\grqq{} and \glq quote\grq.

\noindent
Some derivatives $f'(x)+g''(x)$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will break the usage of `'` in math formulas; just to make it known. Maybe one should use `\global\quoteopenfalse` and `\global\quoteopentrue`.

Comment: @egreg, I was quite sure that it would have broken something else... Do you know a workaround?

Comment: I've added it (and also added `\global` where needed).

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot. I'll take a look at your changes to learn something about them.

Comment: The upper quotation marks are upside down. They should look like a 66 and not like a 99

Comment: @cgnieder I know, this is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @karlkoeller The OP also mentions German standards which no doubt are `„“`

Comment: A German single quote should also begin with a lower quotation mark... while this answer is TeXnically interesting :) the OP really should use `babel` shorthands or `csquotes`

Comment: This is indeed what I asked for. Thank you for this very interesting technical solution and for reading between the lines what I actually wanted. :)

Comment: @cgnieder The last edit adds support for single quotes, too...

Comment: @Mil Glad to help. And I too have learned a lot today ;-)

Comment: No solution is perfect. This one raises an error if primes are used in the TOC (and very likely in other contexts).

Comment: @JavierBezos You're right...

Answer (score 70):

I’d use [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes), with `"` defined as outer quotation mark, like in

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
"Deutscher" Text
\end{document}
```

[image: german quotes]

You can also define a symbol for inner quotations with `\MakeInnerQuote{<symbol>}` or an automated solution which decides wether to use outer or inner quote with `\MakeAutoQuote{<open>}{<close>}` where the two characters must be different, e.g. `\MakeAutoQuote{<}{>}` (use: `<Deutscher> Text`) …

---

Please note, that `\MakeOuterQuote{"}` overwrites some of `babel`’s shorthands in certain languages like `"=` in `(n)german`. In that was it might be better to use another character for active quotes or no active quotes and `\enquote` instead. Otherwise on could define own macros for babel shorthands like

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\diviswithhiphenation}{\penalty\@M-\hskip\z@skip}
% defined like "= in babel-contrib/german/ngermanb.dtx
\makeatother
```

Comment: This solution does not work ideally in my case as I use '' (twice ') and not " for quotations.

Comment: @Mil: Sorry, I overread that. You could search and replace `''` by `"` in your editor …

Comment: @Mil That’s wrong use in the source, then already. See [Anführungszeichen – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anf%C3%BChrungszeichen).

Comment: @Mil: In some editors (I use TexStudio for instance) you have the possibility to choose an option like "replace quotation marks", which will automatically replace `"` with something of your choise (`\enquote{` for instance). The next time your enter `"` this will be replaced by `}`. I quite like this feature.

Comment: The approach of Tobi works perfectly for me

Comment: Works with french quotation, in LaTeX and on overleaf (online LaTeX editor) - thanks a lot. It's so easy now !

Answer (score 22):

The most portable way is to use the `\enquote` command which is defined in the *csquotes* package. Maybe you want to change the quote style later to *guillemets* (>> foo <<), then all you have to do is to change the package option to `\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
    Text without quotes. \enquote{Text with quotes}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was using `\MakeOuterQuote{"}` approach by @Tobi until today, but because one of my bibliography entries generated by zotero plugin had also ", there were some warnings. After applying this and commenting out MakeOuterQuote, i was able to get rid of it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

I don't think `''text''` is the standard way. Use the babel short hands. Here is an example which combines the short hands with the functionality of the csquotes package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=guillemets,maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\defineshorthand{"`}{\openautoquote}
\defineshorthand{"'}{\closeautoquote}

\begin{document}

Das ist ein "`deutscher Text"'.

\end{document}
```

...Rolf

Answer (score 9):

I presume you are using `babel`, so another solution is (in the preamble):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman,math=normal]{babel}

\useshorthands{'}

\newif\ifclosequote
\defineshorthand{''}{%
  \ifclosequote
    \closequotefalse\dq
  \else
    \closequotetrue\glqq
  \fi}
```

As a side effect, `'` is a shorthand character and behaves as such -- for example, things like `{'}` raise an error.

Comment: Use the code between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in the last edit of my answer and you'll see some strange behaviors...

Comment: @karlkoeller `\useshorthands` is a "only preamble" macro. I edited my answer.

Comment: I know, but as I said, see what happens with this code: `A single 'quote' and some derivatives $f'(x)+g''(x)$.`

Comment: @karlkoeller This is one of the side effects I was talking about. As to the primes, just use `math=active`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Oops! I meant `math=normal`.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is not quite what you've been asking, but I can't comment, so I'll answer for completeness:
For the future, do you know that `,,text''` (,,text'') will produce exactly the same output as `\glqq text''` (`\dq` just looks weird when I compile it)? This is probably more convenient to type, if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: In order to type `„` (`U+201E`)you have to know where to find it on your keyboard. It is not available on my standard setup, i have to change to the german layout and then use `<atl + gr> + v`. This is not easier to type.

Comment: Using `\enquote{something}`, you can change the style of qoutes globally, for example to »something« or «something».

Comment: No, at least in my setup (the important part of which seems to be to have \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} in the preamble), if I type two commas, that will compile to the exact same thing as the \glqq ... and finding a comma on a keyboard shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: It wasn't obvious at first, that this are two commas (thatś why highlighting code is important). But this approach still isn't handy when you want to change the style of your quotes.

Comment: Two commas give the same output, thats a good tip!