# German quotation marks in scrartcl with ``text''

Tags: koma-script, german, quotation

Apologies, but I could not find a solution in all the similar questions asked here, so opening new question with my specific problem.

Very simple but long document. Premable more or less just this (+bibtex)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[german]{babel
```

Throughout the text, I am using ``Text'' for quotations.

I am looking for a way to change the output to German quotation marks („Text“) without replacing the way the quotations are done in the text. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome, try using the package `csquotes` as this answer describes and let us know if it works in your document or not: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150945/automatic-german-quotation-marks#150958

Comment: I have tried this solution before, but could not seem to get it to work with a document that uses ``Text''?

(Assume you are referring to the proposed solution of: \usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

Comment: That was the one I was referring to, the csquotes package documentation says your characters cannot be used in section 10.3 (was unaware of this until I read it just now). Hopefully someone will find a solution without csquotes.

Comment: your input creates quotes through font ligatures. To exchange them you would have to change the ligatures in the fonts, possible but not easily (unless you use lualatex where it could probably be done). It is easier to simply search for your quotes and replace them by `\enquote{` and `}`.